# Do I substract 1 from 45 each time a student registers for a seat?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have 2 fieldnames on 2 different tables.

One fieldname is called SeatCapacity. This fieldname name has a value of 45 and it is on a table called Locations

Then there is another field called RemainingSeats on a table called tblMain.

tblMain table contains details of registrations such as loginId of who signed up, course signed up for, date of training, etc.

This RemainingSeats fieldname should contain an initial value of 45 just like SeatCapacity.

Each time an individual signs up for a seat, 1 is substracted from RemainingSeats.

For instance, if RemainingSeats is 45 and I sign up for a seat, RemainingSeats now should only be 44.

This goes on till RemainingSeats is 0 in which case, no one can sign up anymore.

Here are my issues right now.

1, how do I assign initial value of 45 to RemainingSeats?

SeatCapacity should always show total seats to be signed up while RemainingSeats should show only remaining seats.

I tried adding 45 to tblMain in design mode in ssms as defaut value but I can't see this value.

2, When I tried doing an insert statement like:

```
 s = "INSERT INTO tblMain (CourseId, LocationId, dateId,RemainingSeats) VALUES "
        s += "(" & Request.QueryString("cosId") & ", " & Request.QueryString("locid") & ", " & Request.QueryString("iddate") & ",(RemainingSeats-1) )"
```

I get the following error:

*The name "RemainingSeats" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.*

How do I resolve these?

Thanks a lot in advance

The below code is supposed to load training details but right now it shows blank because no record exists in tblMain.

```
SelectCommand="select l.LocationId,c.courseId, c.coursename,tm.trainingMode,t.availableSeats,d.dateid,d.trainingDates, d.trainingtime, c.CourseDescription,i.instructorName, l.location,l.seating_capacity 
                        from tblCourses c,tblMain t,tblTrainingDates d, tblLocations l,tblInstructors i, tblCourseInstructor ic, tblTrainingMode tm
                        where c.courseId = ic.CourseId and i.instructorId = ic.instructorId and l.locationid = c.locationid
                        and c.dateid=d.dateid and t.locationId = l.locationId and tm.trainingModeId = c.trainingModeId" 
              FilterExpression="LocationId = '{0}'" >
        <FilterParameters>
```

Comment: After the insert make an update to tblMain and substract 1 to RamainingSeats field

Comment: please use parametric sql.

Comment: How do you get the initial value to insert in the RemainingSeats? Could you sha the code that retrieves the value from the Locations table?

Comment: You are using some unusual terminology: What is a "fieldname"? And how can a "name" have a value of 45?

Comment: It would be easier for us to help if you included the schemas for your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a place where you keep a SeatCapacity, then why you not copying it from there.

As I noticed you know LocationID before creating row in tblMain, and in Location table you have a SeatCapacity, so SQL query will be:

...Please use parameters for inserted data...

```
INSERT INTO tblMain(CourceId, LocationId, dateId, RemainingSeats) 
(SELECT @CourceID
, @LocationID
, @DateID
, SeatCapacity FROM Locations WHERE ID=@LocationID);
```

in VB.NET adding paramaters will be:

```
Dim param AS New System.Sql.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@CourceID", Request.QueryString("cosId"))
```

... and so on

Then add parameters to your SqlCommand and execute query

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the Locations table has a primary key called `locationID` then your query to set the initial value for the tblMain table could be written

```
s = "INSERT INTO tblMain (CourseId, LocationId, dateId,RemainingSeats) VALUES " +
    "(@cosID, @locID, @dat (SELECT TOP(1) SeatCapacity from Location WHERE LocationID = @locID))"

Dim cmd = new MySqlCommand(s, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codID", Request.QueryString("cosId"))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locID", Request.QueryString("locid")) 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat", Request.QueryString("iddate"))
```

Note that I don't know the exact datatype for CourseID and LocationId, if they are numbers then you need to comvert to number the values retrieved from the querystring

Now the update operation is very simple. Just

```
s = "UPDATE tblMain SET RemainingSeats = RemainingSeats - 1 WHERE " 
    "CourseID = @cosID AND LocationID = @locId AND dateId = @dat"
....
```

Comment: Thank you @Steve, et al. I truly appreciate the time and great help. I just have one follow up question. The process is this: User logs on and is taken to the Training page. On training page, there is a dropdown of locations. Once user chooses location for the training, associated records like instructor, course, location, start date and time are initially loaded. User then clicks register then the insert code you came up with. How do I load that initial page without data in tblMain table?

Please see the code that is supposed to load the training page. Do I need to change to Left Join?

Comment: Yes, in this situation the resultset will be empty. So you need a LEFT JOIN on the tblMain and perhaps on other tables as well.

Comment: or anyone else, I am getting the following error when running the insert statement with subquery:

`Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed. `

Comment: No, it didn't work. However, @Fabio's seems to have worked for me.

The only issue is getting the query with left join to work correctly.

It works but not correctly. I will post that question separately in a minute. If you could help, that would be greatly appreciated.