# I need to insert records if no record already exists. How do I fix this code to do this?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

This code is really driving me nuts.

Earlier today, here in this great forum, I got help with loading initial default values into the db with the following code.

```
 s = "INSERT INTO tblTrainings (CourseId, tblLocations.LocationId, dateId,AvailableSeats) (SELECT @CosID, @LocID, @dat,Seating_Capacity FROM tblLocations, tblCourses WHERE tblCourses.locationId= tblLocations.LocationId and courseId = @cosId and tblLocations.locationID=@LocID)"

 s += "UPDATE tblTrainings SET AvailableSeats = AvailableSeats - 1 WHERE CourseID = @cosID AND LocationID = @locId AND dateId = @dat"
```

History:

I have a dataList with several rows of records and a link that says, "Click here to register.

When you mouse over this link, it shows the IDs of date, course, location.

When a user clicks that link, if checks the db to see if dateId, CourseId, LocationId and AvailableSeats are null.

The Problem:

The issue I was having with the solution above is that each time a user hits the Register link an update to existing record is made. This is good but at same time, a new record is inserted into the db and this is not good.

I decided, therefore, to perform a CHECK first.

Check the db for an existing of record meeting certain criteria (specified in SELECT statement below)

If availableSeats (RemainingSeates) is null and dateId is null and courseid is null and locationid is null, then perform an INSERT statement.

If they are not null, perform an UPDATE statement.

It doesn't matter what I do so far, only UPDATE statements are being performed.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Below is the code I am using:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim username = Session.Item("Username").ToString
        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Try
             Dim s As String
            Dim counter As Integer

            'If AvailableSeats already saved, then don't do an INSERT
            s = "SELECT Count(*) Counter FROM tblTrainings WHERE AvailableSeats Is Null and CourseId is null and LocationId is null and dateId is null"
            'Response.Write(s)
            'Response.End()
            Dim connSt As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Dim connc As New SqlConnection(connSt)
            Dim cmdc As New SqlCommand(s, connc)
            connc.Open()
            cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery()
            counter = cmdc.ExecuteScalar()


            '   Now let's see if we found existing record
            If counter > 0 Then
                s = "INSERT INTO tblTrainings (CourseId, tblLocations.LocationId, dateId,AvailableSeats) (SELECT @CosID, @LocID, @dat,Seating_Capacity FROM tblLocations, tblCourses WHERE tblCourses.locationId= tblLocations.LocationId and courseId = @cosId and tblLocations.locationID=@LocID)"
                s += "UPDATE tblTrainings SET AvailableSeats = AvailableSeats - 1 WHERE CourseID = @cosID AND LocationID = @locId AND dateId = @dat"
            Else
                s += "UPDATE tblTrainings SET AvailableSeats = AvailableSeats - 1 WHERE CourseID = @cosID AND LocationID = @locId AND dateId = @dat"

            End If

            Response.Write(s)
            Response.End()

            Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(s, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cosID", Request.QueryString("cosId"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locID", Request.QueryString("locid"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat", Request.QueryString("iddate"))
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
            'Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was processed
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
            Label1.Text = "Record successfully saved!"


        Catch

            'If the message failed at some point, let the user know
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            Label1.Text = "Your record failed to save, please try again."

        End Try
    End Sub


    s = "IF EXISTS (SELECT TrainingId FROM  tblTrainings WHERE AvailableSeats Is NOT NULL and CourseId is NOT NULL and LocationId is NOT NULL and dateId is NOT NULL) "
    s += " BEGIN " '***Record already exists in the tblTrainings table, update existing record instead instead***
    s += "UPDATE tblTrainings SET AvailableSeats = AvailableSeats - 1 WHERE CourseID = @cosID AND LocationID = @locId AND dateId = @dat "
    s += " End "
    s += " ELSE "
    s += " BEGIN " '***No record exists in the tblTrainings table; create one and update it at same time.***
    s += " INSERT INTO tblTrainings (CourseId, tblLocations.LocationId, dateId,AvailableSeats) (SELECT @CosID, @LocID, @dat,Seating_Capacity FROM tblLocations, tblCourses WHERE tblCourses.locationId= tblLocations.LocationId and courseId = @cosId and tblLocations.locationID=@LocID)"
    s += "UPDATE tblTrainings SET AvailableSeats = AvailableSeats - 1 WHERE CourseID = @cosID AND LocationID = @locId AND dateId = @dat"
    s += " End "
```

Comment: As a rule, if you don't need a count, don't get one.  Use [`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx?ppud=4) to check if any row matching some condition exists.  Your test for existence seems to have a very different `WHERE` clause than your `UPDATE`.  I wouldn't expect them to find the same row(s), hence you keep inserting non-NULL values and then updating the new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do with filter condition ....

```
Dim cmd as SqlCommand
Dim s1 as String = "" '----> insert stat

s = "UPDATE tblTrainings SET AvailableSeats = AvailableSeats - 1 WHERE CourseID = @cosID AND LocationID = @locId AND dateId = @dat"

conn.Open()    
If counter = 0 Then
    'here is the code you can get value for availableseat 

    s1 = "INSERT INTO tblTrainings (CourseId, tblLocations.LocationId, dateId,AvailableSeats) VALUES (@CosID, @LocID, @dat, @Capacity)" 

    Response.Write(s1)
    Response.End()

    cmd = New SqlCommand(s1, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cosID", Request.QueryString("cosId"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locID", Request.QueryString("locid"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat", Request.QueryString("iddate"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@capacity",  ... ) '----------------> fill the value 

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()     
End If

Response.Write(s)
Response.End()

cmd = New SqlCommand(s, conn)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cosID", Request.QueryString("cosId"))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locID", Request.QueryString("locid"))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat", Request.QueryString("iddate"))

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: @kenny : I'm add some .. you can try it !

Comment: please see below what I have when I ran it with the debugger:

`INSERT INTO tblTrainings (CourseId, tblLocations.LocationId, dateId,AvailableSeats) (SELECT @CosID, @LocID, @dat,Seating_Capacity FROM tblLocations, tblCourses WHERE tblCourses.locationId= tblLocations.LocationId and courseId = @cosId and tblLocations.locationID=@LocID)`

It doesn't matter whether I click the update an existing record or I click to insert a record that doesn't exist, I get the above.

Similar to the issue I am having.

Comment: @Kenny : sorry I'm wrong .. Yes your insert statement is wrong .. it's changed but I don't know about data to fill to Availableseat ..

Comment: Your idea of adding value in parameters insert - this below:

`   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@capacity",  ... ) '----------------> fill the value `, helped me solve this problem.

Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score -1):

You need a **semicolon** at the end of the INSERT statement:

```
If counter > 0 Then
    s = "INSERT INTO tblTrainings (CourseId, tblLocations.LocationId, 
    dateId,AvailableSeats) 
(SELECT @CosID, @LocID, @dat,Seating_Capacity FROM tblLocations, tblCourses 
WHERE tblCourses.locationId= tblLocations.LocationId 
and courseId = @cosId and tblLocations.locationID=@LocID);"
    s += "UPDATE tblTrainings SET AvailableSeats = AvailableSeats - 1 
WHERE CourseID = @cosID AND LocationID = @locId AND dateId = @dat"
Else
    s += "UPDATE tblTrainings SET AvailableSeats = AvailableSeats - 1 
WHERE CourseID = @cosID AND LocationID = @locId AND dateId = @dat"

End If
```

Comment: @matzone, we need both the insert statement and update statement. Initially, values are loaded by selecting from appropriate tables.

Then an update is performed at same time. So, that's not the issue.

Hugo, I tried adding semicolon but no difference. It usually says, `Insert Successful` but no record is inserted.

HABO, I just switched to EXISTS but same result. See updated code above.

Comment: I needed to add that the UPDATE statements works very nicely. It is the INSERT/Update combo that isn't inserting.

Comment: Single statements need a semicolon in sql server?

Comment: Well, I agree but at this point, I am just grabbing at straws.

Comment: @Kenny - Usually one either updates an existing row or inserts a row with the correct data.  Doing an insert and immediately correcting the data is a bit odd.  You are also pulling the decision making out of the database and into your application code.  Without an explicit transaction wrapping the activity you are allowing a race condition where you check for a row, someone else creates the row, you create the row based on the check, ... .

Comment: @HABO, This link below will help probably explain what we are trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877302/do-i-substract-1-from-45-each-time-a-student-registers-for-a-seat/16877478#16877478 Could you please go over it and maybe you will understand what I am trying to do and perhaps suggest a better way to handle it. 

They provided the solution but I didn't realize it wasn't complete till I started testing it.

Comment: @Kenny - Sorry, but I had been watching that question and it never made sense to me.  There seem to be a lot of issues and SO isn't the place to discuss them.

Comment: @HABO, I am going to attempt to explain once more what I am trying to do. I have a few tables, course, locations, tblDates, Instructors. These tables are prepopulated with that.

The Locations table has a field called SeatingCapacity and has a default value of 45. 

Users select course they want to take, location, date and then they click Register to register this course. Once they register, the There is a field in tblTrainings table called AvailableSeats. Once a user registers, total AvailableSeats drops by one until it hits 0. Problem is the value needs to be loaded first. That's the problem

Comment: To echo HABO's point above - you may be better served by putting this business logic into a stored procedure and take the logic out of your VB.